# Why are two options present for right shift? (arithmetic / logical)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Why does right shift have two choices — appending the sign bit (arithmetic right shift) or appending 0 (logical right shift) and why does the implementation get to choose which?

Comment: yeah. I am able to get that. So why does appending sign bit come into picture for right shift?

Comment: Left shifting is already arithmetic; it's the same as multiplying by a power of two.  Filling in the least-significant-bits with sign-bits makes no sense.

Comment: True. Please help me understand the same for right shift

Comment: Why people downvoting the question? please add comment? I think its an obvious question. Is it duplicate from somewhere?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'C'? You don't have that choice, in C. Java has [`>>` and `>>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) that allows you to differentiate between the two kinds of shift, but C does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is to allow the handling of both signed (two's complement) and unsigned integers.

- When right-shifting a signed (two's complement) integer the
  most-significant bit is the sign; 0 for positive or zero, and 1 for
  negative. In order to retain the sign on the right-shift, one must
  duplicate the existing high-order bit, or *appending* the sign as you
  prefer .
- When right-shifting an unsigned integer, in order to retain the
  magnitude properly one must append zero on the left regardless of the
  existing high-order bit.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to shift the sign bit as well, i believe you are looking for a circular left shift operation and not a "standard left shift" operation.

you could look at the question posed on the following link:
[Circular shift in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289397/circular-shift-in-c)

For a better understanding of bitwie operations you could look at the following wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: +1 for mentioning circular shift.  -1 for 'right shift should not be implementation dependent'.  It is implementation dependent for (negative) signed values.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Deleted my statement about the shift not being implementation dependent. Didn't consider negative values when i wrote it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
> resulting value is implementation-deﬁned.

I guess you are referring to this paragraph.

This is because the standard does not define how a negative number will be stored (2's complement, 1's complement, etc.) - it is implementation defined (hardware dependent).

It is "almost" the same for left shift on signed integers.

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are ﬁlled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> **is representable in the result type**, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undeﬁned**.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is nonsensical.  In a two's complement system, the sign of a number is determined by its highest order bit.  For a right shift, you can either decide to shift in a zero (logical shift) or a copy of the sign bit (arithmetic shift).  For a left shift, the only meaningful operation is to shift in zero.

Comment: Hi Carl. Thanks! Now `For a right shift, you can either decide to shift in a zero (logical shift) or a copy of the sign bit (arithmetic shift)`. In what case the either of them changes?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean, you say, in a right shift we either decide to shift a zero, or copy the sign bit. Why is that??

Comment: @CHID: Because when right-shifting, there's a choice between doing an arithmetic right-shift or a logical right-shift.  Implementations get to choose.  If they choose arithmetic, they must preserve the sign bit and do sign-extension (so `-64 >> 1` produces -32).  When left-shifting, there is no such choice.

Comment: @jamesdlin Still that `if` clause baffles me. So I will put the question like this. When do they choose arithmetic and when do they choose logical?

Comment: Usually they choose depending on the underlying instruction set they're writing the compiler for.  It's really just a design choice though.

Comment: @CHID: It's an arbitrary choice.  They could flip a coin for all you care.  If you want arithmetic right-shift, just use `/`.  If you want logical right-shift, you probably shouldn't be using signed integer types in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Under a twos complement representation, a "normal" left-shift acts exactly like an arithmetic left-shift: left-shifting a negative number results in that number being doubled (as long as the result does not overflow).